# please help me translate this poem on my dizi into english

Tags: mandarin, character-identification

[image]

picture shows chinese writing on my dizi

Answer (score 1):

If it's "笛鸣天下曲, 箫声韵五孤", its translation should be:

```
The flute can play all the tunes in the world

all its voice sounds so lonely but fair
```

Because I do not know is the last Chinese Character "孤", so I only can translate it to "lonely" now.

Actually, "笛" and "箫" are two kind of flutes, but it seem both their English translation are "flute".

Comment: I think it is probably 五洲 instead of 五孤. 五洲 means five continents, which basically means the whole world. It can be the counterpart of 天下 in the first half of the sentence.

Comment: It's probably. If so, it was wrote by a poet lived in modern time - ancient poet didn't know 五洲.

Answer (score -2):

笛鸣天下曲箫声
this is a bit wired, i can't find its source.
the first character is dizi;
笛鸣 means the dizi is is crying or cries
天下 means the world, metaphorically
曲箫 is not a word. imo, 曲 is a noun, means absolute music, without lyrics, 箫 is a noun, instrument.
声 is sound.

This sentence is a poem-liked, very confusing, though, it maybe means nothing.It is likely someone love classic literature but really suck at it, as consquence, wrote a bad sentence, looks great at first but in fact something bad.

I saw I was downvoted, that I want to say more.

There are many people who are really suck at classic Chinese love writing sentences meant nothing but look classic and greatful. We had lots of discussion already.
https://www.zhihu.com/question/27426102

Comment: I don't think so. In my opinion, it should be "笛鸣天下曲, 箫声韵五孤", but I'm not sure if the last Chinese Character is "孤".

Comment: @T-Pioneer That make sense. Thank you! I didn't understand the last character.

Comment: I don't understand the last Character either. What's "五孤"?

Comment: I also don't like those cofusing poem-like sentences!

Comment: could the last character be an author? a family character symbol?

Comment: @Tommy It seem that its author is "李*". I cannot see it clearly.